# Pass Parameters to Custom Microsoft.FeatureManagement.IFeatureFilter

Tags: c#, azure, feature-flags

I have a custom feature filter for Client ids.  Right now, I have it working where I check if the "clientId" is found in the `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query` and if it is found, it checks if that clientId is in the `AllowedClientIds` property of `ClientFilterSettings`.  I get the `ClientFilterSettings` via `var settings = context.Parameters.Get<ClientFilterSettings>();`

The issue is, the clientId might not always be in the `Request.Query`.  It might be in a User's claims `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims`.  I need a way for the person writing the code to specify, "for this action, look in the claims" or "for this action, look in the query params".  There are other scenarios like, maybe it's in a dto in a POST and not necessarily the `clientId` in the route parameter.  Or even possibly, send the clientId in the `await _featureManager.IsEnabledAsync("clientIdFeature", clientId)`.  I know we can send an IContext to the  `IsEnabledAsync`, but I can't overwrite the context as I specified above, I use the context to get the `AllowedClientIds` property.

Is there a way to append to the current context or some other way to get information into the filter per instance it is used (ex: per action route)?